# To find the value of $X^2+Y^2$

Tags: matrices

If X and Y are two singular matrices such that $XY = Y$ and $YX = X$, then $X^2+Y^2$ equals to

(A) $X+Y$ (B) $XY$ (C) $YX$ (D) $2(X+Y)$

what I tried is $X^2 + Y^2 = XX+YY$ then putting $XY = Y$ and $YX = X$ in the equation I got $YX^2+XY^2$. how do I proceed from here

Answer (score 4):

$$X^2=XYX=YX=X$$

$$Y^2=YXY=XY=Y$$

Answer (score 3):

$$X^2+Y^2=(YX)^2+(XY)^2=YXYX+XYXY$$ Now as $YX=X$, then $Y=XY=YXY$, or, $XY=XYXY$. Similarly $YX=YXYX$. Hence $YXYX+XYXY=YX+XY=X+Y$. So $$X^2+Y^2=X+Y$$